# Spring Cloud Stub Runner Boot Application and Cloud Stream (Kafka) for Smoke Test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-contract

In a microservice architecture I have three services. The first one creates a message in a kafka queue with spring cloud stream. In this service I use spring cloud contract to generate a contract. The second service is a spring cloud stub runner boot service that reads the contracts of the first service and exposes them to the third service. The third service does smoke test against the stub runner service using the endpont /triiggers/{label}. I understand that when I call to /triggers/{label} the service stub runner should send the message created in the service contract to the kafka queue, but never it send it to the queue. How can I do the stub runner service send the message of the contract to the kafka queue?.
Thanks

Code:

**Service 1**

Contract:

```
org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract.make {

    description 'Register event: Customer registered'

    label 'CustomerRegistered'

    input {
        // the contract will be triggered by a method
        triggeredBy('registerEvent()')
    }
    // output message of the contract
    outputMessage {
        // destination to which the output message will be sent
        sentTo 'ClassCustomerEvent'
        // the body of the output message
        body('''{"id":1,"eventType":"CustomerRegistered","entity": {"clientId":1,"clientName":"David, Suarez, Pascual","classCalendarId":1,"classCalendarName":"Aula 1 - Aerobic","classCalendarDayId":7}}''')
    headers {
        header('contentType', applicationJson())
    }
}
```

}

**Service 2:**

application.yml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost
          zkNodes: localhost
      default-binder: kafka

stubrunner:
  cloud:
    stubbed:
      discovery:
        enabled: false

stubrunner:
  stubsMode: LOCAL
  ids:
    - com.elipcero.classcustomerschool:classcustomer-school:1.0.0:stubs:8762
```

Main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableStubRunnerServer
@EnableBinding
@AutoConfigureStubRunner
public class ClassCustomerStubrunnerSchoolApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

SpringApplication.run(ClassCustomerStubrunnerSchoolApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

**Service 3**

SmokeTest:

```
@Test
public void should_calculate_client_total_by_classrooom_and_set_class_by_client() {

    mongoOperations.dropCollection("CustomerClass");
    mongoOperations.dropCollection("ClassCustomerDayTotal");

    String url = this.stubRunnerUrl + "/triggers/CustomerRegistered";

    log.info("Mongo collections deletes");
    log.info("Url stub runner boot: " + url);

    ResponseEntity<Map> response = this.restTemplate.postForEntity(url, "", Map.class);
    then(response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()).isTrue();

    log.info("Triggered customer event");

    await().until( () ->
         customerClassRepository
                 .findById(1)
                 .map((c) -> c.getClasses().isEmpty())
                 .orElse(false)
    );
 }
```

Sink:

```
@Service
@EnableBinding(ClassCustomerConsumer.class)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ClassCustomerEvent {

    public static final String CONST_EVENT_CUSTOMER_REGISTERED = "CustomerRegistered";
    public static final String CONST_EVENT_CUSTOMER_UNREGISTERED = "CustomerUnregistered";

    @NonNull private ClassCustomerTotalView classCustomerTotalView;
    @NonNull private CustomerClassView customerClassView;

    @StreamListener(ClassCustomerConsumer.INPUT)
    public void ConsumeClassCustomerEvent(EventMessage<ClassCustomer> eventMessage) {
        classCustomerTotalView.calculate(eventMessage);
        customerClassView.selectOrUnSelected(eventMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here you have an example of such a scenario with rabbit https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/github-analytics-stub-runner-boot. Can you check it out and see if you're doing things in the same way?

Comment: Thanks, I have based on https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/github-analytics-stub-runner-boot and I think that i'm doing in the same way.

Comment: I have seem that the created channel is a DirectChannel with a dispatch handler of type org.springframework.cloud.stream.test.binder.TestSupportBinder. This handler store the messages in memory. Is there any way to use kafka handler instead of stream test binder?

Comment: Have you excluded the autoconfig? TestSupportBinderAutoConfiguration?

Comment: Yes, I have used @SpringBootApplication( exclude = { TestSupportBinderAutoConfiguration.class}) but not working. I don't know why?

Comment: Can you upload the code to github?

Comment: Yes, The stub runner is here: https://github.com/davsuapas/DanceSchool/tree/Smoke_Test/ClassCustomerStubrunnerSchool and The contract is here: https://github.com/davsuapas/DanceSchool/blob/Smoke_Test/ClassCustomerSchool/src/test/resources/contracts/events/register.groovy

Comment: I think that the problem is in StubRunnerStreamsIntegrationAutoConfiguration beacuse adding TestSupportBinderAutoConfiguration into ImportAutoConfiguration. Althougth it should work ConditionalOnClass. I think that this class wasn't in the Dalston.SR3 version that was used in the github-analytics-stub-runner-boot sample

Comment: Great analysis let me try and bump that version to Finchley and let's see what happens

Comment: Worst case scenario you can use Edgware or Dalston for now as a workaround, right?

Comment: Ok ,I going to try it

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in master for the next version after of spring-cloud-contract-v2.1.0.M2

Issue reference: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/pull/805